# Play store says that my app must have targetSDK at least 28. What If I don't?

Tags: android, google-play-console

While I was uploading an update for my app on google PlayStore, it showed a warning that said that my app must have `target sdk >= 28` until August. My app uses `target sdk = 27`

**Question**

What if I don't do that?? PlayStore does not say what will happen to those who don't make these changes...
Should I worry about it and try refactoring my app?

**Why I am asking?**

I am using a library which is not working well with targetSDK 28 as it gives me errors.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with a proper answer from Google that I got today that answers properly your question as it should be. So, technically, as I said before you should refactor your app if not sooner or later your app won't be available in Android devices since most of phones are/are going to be ARM 64 not 32.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Thankfully I made some changes and now my project has the desired target sdk. The problem was with clipRect()

Comment: Hi, it seems that @Pierre agrees that you could change his answer to my one as the correct one. Have a good day.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete Sure no problem, I would have given you both the correct answer but it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google set new requirements since this year, an abstract of the new policy:

> When you upload an APK, it needs to meet Google Play’s target API
>   level requirements. Starting August 1, 2019, Google Play requires that
>   new apps target at least Android 9.0 (API level 28), and that app
>   updates target Android 9.0 from November 1, 2019. Until these dates,
>   new apps and app updates must target at least Android 8.0 (API level
>   26).

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Also, you must have a arm64 for all new upgrades, more info:

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need
>   to support 64-bit architectures. 64-bit CPUs deliver faster, richer
>   experiences for your users. Adding a 64-bit version of your app
>   provides performance improvements, makes way for future innovation,
>   and sets you up for devices with 64-bit-only hardware.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Regarding, the library you can try recompiling it if you have the code or contact the developer.

**Update:**

I got this answer today (10/07/2019 at 11:37) from **Google Directly**:

> To provide both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, you can either: have
>   support for both in the same APK or app bundle; or you can have a
>   release with multiple APKs where 1 APK supports 32-bit and another
>   supports 64-bit.
>
> **From August 1, 2021 apps that do not have a 64-bit version available**
>   **will no longer be served to users with 64-bit compatible devices.**
>   **Please note, 32-bit devices will still be served 32-bit compatible**
>   **versions. We are not changing our policies on serving 32-bit releases.**
>
> Please note that this requirement does not apply to:
>
> APKs or app bundles explicitly targeting Wear OS or Android TV, which
>   are form factors that do not currently support 64-bit code.
>
> APKs or app bundles that are not distributed to devices running
>   Android 9 Pie or later.
>
> To begin updating your apps to meet these new requirements we highly
>   recommend reading through the relevant documents in the Android
>   Developer Center:
>   https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
>
> For developers using Android NDK, please check the following
>   information on APIs for developing native code:
>
> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis
>
> Please check our blog for updates on this announcement:
>
> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: Yes okay but do you know what happens to the current apps in playstore that use a lower target sdk?? Will they remove them??

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos, I read something like this: Older apps that aren’t being updated anymore can still target old versions of the OS, but many of these apps end up being removed over time as they run afoul of new Play Store policies. https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/260880-google-will-require-future-android-apps-64-bit-support-updated-apis

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos, I'd check the new policies in detail, but as fara as I remember they will be removed. I just upgraded my ones and yes, I replaced or rebuild some of the libraries in my case.

Comment: I agree with Google's position @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos for 2 reasons, first they want to improve the quality of the Apps in the Play Store and 2nd, I think when you download any app you expect efficiency, small size and fast response. Google is not the only company that has standards, Apple has pushed similar things in the past like since the next upgrade all apps for macOS must be x64 and it's understandable. I could agree your position as a developer too that it's not easy to upgrade an app with 3rd party libraries, but it's part of the challenge in IT.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to *upload a new version* of the app after the deadline that doesn't follow the requirements. Existing versions of the app won't be affected (at least in the immediate future).

Comment: Are you really sure that it will not be affected?

Comment: Hi @Pierre, I got today an answer from Google that says something slightly different. These kinds of apps (arm32) are not going to be available to arm64 devices (which are going to be the majority in the near future or are already, I couldn't find a chart) since Aug 1st, 2021. Therefore, as I advised the best idea is to refactor the app.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer to reflect this other further deadline. Your solution is now more complex and should probably be accepted instead of mine.

Comment: Maybe you should provide that advice to Kwnstantinos Nikoloutsos, @Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem as such but it is good to have latest targetSdk as that is the latest sdk and will be supported by the newer devices and the user reach will be more as many people will be having devices which supports sdk Version greater than 27.

Comment: Do you mean that my app will not be removed for using targetSDK 27 ?

Comment: Not at all till November 1, 2019 as mentioned by Federico.

Answer (score 0):

First I uploaded target level 28 not accepted. I changed it to 29 and uploaded successfull. Than as an update, I uploaded target level 28, and it is accepted (in review now).

I guess, new apk should be 29 after August but until the November, level 28 is accepted as update.