# Why users with android 8.1 and lower can not see my app in the play store

Tags: android

I upload my app in the play store with minimum android version 9.0 (API Level 28) because play store does not allow upload app with minimum android version 8.1 (API Level 27).

Now many users can not see the app in the play store.

What can i do to the user with android version 8.1 and lower?

How Whatsapp do to users with android version 8.1 and lower?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

Comment: And [Play store says that my app must have targetSDK at least 28. What If I don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56792612/295004)

Comment: Hi, in that cuestion does not response how can i do for user with android 8.1 and lower. and how whatsapp upload the app and users with android 8.1 and lower can see it in the play store.

Comment: Most likely you've set your minSDK to a value API 28 (preventing lower devices from seeing your app) and confusing `minSDK` with `targetSDK`. Review what you've configured/tested and [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59313020/edit) your question with why that isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of me "build.gradle" (Module:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 8
        versionName "0.008"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

This app can be posted to Play Store ,
it may be because my "minSdkVersion" = 21 ,
so my Android 6.0 phone can download.
I'm not sure if it can be changed ,
I chose it when I was building 
Hope that helps you!